# Angular protractor testing a login feature

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I want to test a login flow but with this code I get the following error:
  **- Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, mat-simple-snackbar)**

```
  describe('After login', () => {
   it('should show login message', () => {
   const emailInput = element.all(by.xpath('//*[@id="mat-input-1"]'));
   const passwordInput = element.all(by.xpath('//*[@id="mat-input-2"]'));
   emailInput.sendKeys('user@domain.com');
   passwordInput.sendKeys('Passw0rd!');

  element(by.css('#mat-dialog-0 > login-form')).click().then(() => {
    browser.waitForAngular().then(() => {
      const loginMessage = element(by.tagName('mat-simple-snackbar'));
      expect(loginMessage.getText()).toEqual('Du är nu inloggad');
    });
  });
 });
});
```

When the .click() is triggered a dialog with the loginform closes and page loads, but the snack-bar can't be found?

Comment: Since you have instructed to wait for angular, then the error will only mean that the `mat-simple-snackbar` tag is not there in the page after the click

Comment: hmm not sure I follow.. on click angular start the login right? so when finished it element should be there!(?)

Comment: Yeah It looks like that but cannot tell unless we see it. Do a manual login and inpect the elements, do you see an element with tag `mat-simple-snackbar`?

Comment: Yepp.. I sure do :)

Comment: Okay, I have myself not used `waitForAngular()` but I always used `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)`, can you try and check once?

Comment: hmm.. guess I have other issues.. even if I use a bad password I get inconsistent behavior :P ... need to do some more reading...

Comment: I did find out that the proxy specified in proxy.conf is not used.. any idea how to do that?

Comment: Nope, haven't used any files like `proxy.conf` myself. You can have a look at the files.. `angular-cli.json` and `package.json` to see if you can configure your `proxy.conf` file

Comment: The proxy is working just fine when running the app.. just not for the e2e test :/